# Best practices: working with DB in Java

Tags: java, database

First of all, I'm new to Java.

I'm trying to figure out what would be a good/handy way to work with DB from Java. I'm using c3p0 for connection pooling. Hibernate or other ORM is not an option this time, we decided to stick with "plain SQL" for now.

Currently basic retrieval of data looks like this:

```
private int getUserID(int sessionID, String userIP) {
 int result = 0;
 Connection conn = null;
 PreparedStatement st = null;
 ResultSet rs = null;
 try {
  // Application.cpds is an instance of c3p0's ComboPooledDataSource
  conn = Application.cpds.getConnection();
  st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT user_id, user_ip, is_timed_out FROM g_user.user_session WHERE id = ?");
  st.setInt(1, sessionID);
  rs = st.executeQuery();
  if ( rs.next() ) {
   if ( !rs.getBoolean("is_timed_out") && userIP.equals(rs.getString("user_ip")) ) {
    result = rs.getInt("user_id");
   }
  }
 }
 catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 finally {
  if ( rs != null ) {
   try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }
  if ( st != null ) {
   try { st.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }
  if ( conn != null ) {
   try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }
 }
 return result;
}
```

The code looks very long for such a basic operation. Another problem is that most of the code would have to be repeated in many places (declaring Connection, PreparedStatement, ResultSet, closing them, catching exceptions). Though, this is what I see in most examples when googling.

In PHP I would create a wrapper class that would have method select() that accepts 2 arguments (string)sqlQuery and (array)parameters and would return simple array of data. Wrapper class would also have few more specific methods, like:

- selectValue() for single value (e.g., `select count(*) from user`)
- selectRow() for single row (e.g., `select name, surname from user where id = :user_id`)
- selectColumn for single column (e.g., `select distinct remote_address from user`)

Is anything like this practiced in Java? Or is there anything better / handier? Or should I use same style as in `getUserID()` example above? As I said, ORM is not an option this time.

Thanks in advance :)

---

**edit:** Currently `DBConnection` class is written. It gets connection from c3p0 connection pool in constructor. It has few public methods for working with DB: `select()` for tabular data, `selectValue()` for single value, `selectRow()` and `selectColumn()` for single row or column, as well as `insert()`, `update()`, `delete()` and `ddl()`. Methods accept `String query, Object[] params` arguments, with `params` being optional. `insert()`, `update()` and `delete()` return `Integer` which is result of `PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()`. `select` methods return different results:

- `ArrayCollection<HashMap<String, Object>> select()`
- `Object selectValue()`
- `HashMap<String, Object> selectRow()`
- `ArrayCollection<Object> selectColumn()`

The last problem is with compiler warnings - `"warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast"`. This is because all methods call single private method that returns `Object` and cast its result to mentioned types. As I am new to Java, I'm also not sure if I have chosen  appropriate types for selects. Other than that, everything seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the an ORM is no option, you could still use Spring's JDBC helper classes: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

Or you could simply write some helper methods on your own. Maybe a `DBUtil.close(conn, st, rs);` would be nice.

And by the way, you really should use a logging framework instead of "`e.printStackTrace()`"

**EDIT:**
One more thing: I think it's kind of hard to add ORM afterwards, when you have all the SQL already written in plain JDBC. You can't refactor that stuff, you have to throw it away and do it again.

**EDIT:**
You don't have to close the resultSet if you are closing the statement anyway. The [Java ResultSet API](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) reads:

> A ResultSet object is automatically
>   closed when the Statement object that
>   generated it is closed, re-executed,
>   or used to retrieve the next result
>   from a sequence of multiple results.

Beside that, C3P0 does resource management as well and and closes Statements when you return a connection. You might to look that up too.

Comment: About logging - yeah, I should. Haven't had any time yet to look into it though, but I have it in my todo list ;)

Comment: It's a nobrainer, if you just grap log4j. Should only take two or three hours to get your head around the concepts and integrate it: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/

Comment: Yeah, I know that it should not be too difficult, but it is not on top of my todo list. Basics of working with DB, Red5 "shared objects" and streaming are of higher priority. When those things are learned, I'll take a look into logging. Writing application won't be started until then (for now I'm just writing some test code to see how things work), so logging can be added later with no problems.

Comment: About adding ORM later - it's obvious that changing existing code to ORM will be hard as it will introduce completely different data structures. But can't ORM and "plain SQL" exist paralelly? Anyway, if we decide to move to Java completely, all the code will have to be rewritten. For now Java will act only as a helper-server and do only few things that can't be efficiently done in PHP, main functionality is implemented in PHP.

Comment: Yes, plain SQL and ORM can exist side by side. I just meant, SQL isn't the first step and ORM the second on top of that, but a replacement. I it seem you allready figured that stuff out. Nevermind.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the repetition of code and perhaps makes things simpler.
What you could do is create a Database class.

In the class you could then create general purpose methods for access to the database.
For eg.

if the class is called DBManager.java then inside
create methods

```
private connect()
public boolean update()
public ResultSet query()
```

Reason for connect method is obvious, you use it get your connection. Since its private you call it in the constructor of DBManager.

You then use your update() method to allow you to perform SQL inserts,update,delete and the like, basically any SQL operation that doesn't return any data except for maybe a status of its success is done with the update method.

Your query method is used when you want to do a select query. You can thn return the resultset and then iterate through the results in the calling method/class

How you handle exceptions is up to you. It may be nicer on you to handle exceptions in the DBManager class that way you won't have to handle them in the various classes that you make a query from.

So instead of

```
public ResultSet query() Throws SQLException{
```

you would use a try catch inside the query method like you did in your examples above.
The obvious advantage of handling it in the dbmanager class is that you won't have to worry about it in all the other classes that make use of your sql connection.

Hope that's helpful

in response to your comment:

Its up to you what you return, the ResultSet being return is only an idea but maybe it'd be best to return a collection of some sort instead of an array, maybe? depending on what you need. The resultset needn't be closed.

```
public ResultSet query(String strSql) {

        try {
            Statement tmpStatement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = tmpStatement.executeQuery(strSql);
            return resultSet;
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException ex) {
           //handle exception here
            return null;
        }
    }
```

your update can then look like so

```
public boolean updateSql(String strSQL) {
         try {
            Statement tmpStatement = connection.createStatement();
            tmpStatement.executeUpdate(strSQL);
           return true;
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException ex) {
            //handle exception
            return false;
        }
}
```

erm, you can then use your query method like so

```
 ResultSet r = query(sql);

        try {

            while (r.next()) {
                someVar[i] = r.getString("columnName");           
            }
        } catch (SomeException ex) {
           //handle exception etc
        }
```

But then again as you said instead of returning a result set you could change the query method to copy your results to an array or collection and then return the collection and close the statement with

```
tmpStatement.close();
```

But when a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.(from api docs)

Its good practice to free up database resources as soon as so copying your result to a collection object and then closing your statement is probably best. Again its up to you.

Comment: That's what I did in PHP - I created similar class. What worries me though is that you suggest to return ResultSet as a result of query() - wouldn't some kind of array be better? I believe I would get lots of exceptions (rather than results) because statements would be closed before I start working with ResultSet...

Comment: edited my original answer to respond to your comment. didn't reply here because i wanted to use the code formatting. :-)

Comment: My current implementation of `select()` returns `ArrayCollection<HashMap<String, Object>>`, where `HashMap<String, Object>` holds info about each row (column names and their values), see original post for more. Leaving statements "opened" (i.e., creating them and not calling `.close()`) seems to be very wrong, so ResultSet won't be available outside function. And even if statement would not be closed, it would anyway be garbage-collected at some point of time and ResultSet would be broken then.

Answer (score 0):

" Hibernate or other ORM is not an option this time, we decided to stick with "plain SQL" for now."
Out of curiosity, what was the reason to stick with plain SQL? Looking at the example and question you mentioned first obvious answer would be use ORM and don't bother - in most cases standard ORM feature list would be sufficient.

Obviously there are plenty of reasons not to use ORM's, so I'm interested in yours?

Comment: Our team of 2 coders has never worked with neither Java nor ORM, and Java will be a "helper-server" for now, so we aren't interested in spending too much time to study things that we are not familiar with. Though, if Java some day becomes "main server", we will eventually look into ORM.

Comment: From my experience it would not require too much time to get to know for example JPA which I prefer since moved from JDBC couple years ago, especially if you know SQL. That's obviously only from my perspective, but I can say that in the long run it could save you a lot of problems in the future and speed up development.

Comment: Btw, one thing that worries us about ORM is its capability to replace some complex queries, e.g., recursive queries.

Comment: I think every solution will have pros and cons, depending on what developers are more comfortable with. I have noticed however that in some cases people not using ORM end up building one in their projects anyway. There is always a need for a basic set of operations to be implemented and I think ORM will get the grunt work done so you can focus on writing the code that actually does something rather than reimplementing inserts, updates etc.
But hey, that's only my opinion on the subject :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the level o granularity is always a developer decision. I mean, the great thing of having so many exceptions and validations is that you can capture the specific error and act according to it, however if what you need doesn't require that level of robustness and as you are showing it is just to print out the stack trace, I think a wrapper method can be useful in your case.